# Highcharts display grid over plot with z-index

Tags: css, highcharts

I'm trying to display a graph with the xAxis and yAxis grid lines overlayed on top of the plot.

I can set the zIndex of the plot, but there doesn't seem to be an option to set the zIndex of the grid.
If it's not possible, I can lower the opacity of the plot so that the grid shows through from underneath, but I'd rather not do it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find a way. Even setting zIndex on the series to -99 makes no difference. Have you considered using plot lines or plot bands to draw your own? These both support zIndex.

Update:

Original poster found that the highstock gridZIndex option works for highcharts.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.gridZIndex

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Thought about using plot lines but it seems a little complicated, no?

Comment: A bit more complicated, but may be the only way to control the z order

Comment: Wow, just discovered gridZIndex accidentally! (was just messing around, following Highcharts style nomenclature). Undocumented/possibly unsupported?

Comment: Seems to be documented in the Highstocks docs, but it works in Highcharts just fine.